# Django Translation Files - Integrating legacy translations into .po files

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I have a legacy/non-django application where I have translation files that are in a different format from Django/gettext `.po` files. I would like to use all the strings in my Django application, but I would also like to continue using them in the existing application.

The format of the current system is:

1. Every language has it's own file. (ie. `en.txt`, `de.txt`, `fr.txt`)
2. Each line has a string translated in to it's own language
3. When a string is used in application, the line number that matches that string is first found in `en.txt` and the same line is returned from the target language. So if the string was "hello world" and on line 5 of en.txt, the function would return line 5 of de.txt which would be "hallo welt".

What is the best way to use the old translation files within Django?

Here are a few ideas I've thought of

1. Override the `gettext` system in Django to return my own translations
2. Create my own template tags to handle translation
3. Create a script to create `.po` files from the `.txt` files

Comment: 1) by far. The old format is very fragile and hard to debug: a missing line in one of the translation files, you'd have to trace back to the first not-matching translation. So convert it to something that is well supported and built-in. Once you have .po files, you can still decide for a different system if you want to, and it will be very likely a different system will have a .po importer.

Comment: @Melvyn The issue is that I'll still have to maintain the old txt files since old applications rely on them. But I could create a script to reimport them in to the Django app whenever a change is made

Comment: You have my sympathies. Legacy is a cruel mistress. :) I would press to migrate the old applications to gettext, but if that cannot be done, perhaps use a service like Crowdin and write the translations in the format native to that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, I decided that overriding the internal Django `TranslationCatalog` was possible but appears undocumented and subject to change in the future. For example, if you wanted to add/override a translation, you could do the following:

```
from django.utils import translation

translation._trans._translations['de']._catalog._catalogs[1]['Hello World'] = 'Hallo Welt'
```

For #2, this would work just fine, but I would have to reimplement many of the features of the Django translation system if Django changed it's internal data structures.

For #3, this seemed the most viable since it would allow me to keep using the old text files, but have a script process them whenever something changed. Below is the generic version of what I created for us:

```
lans_dir = 'path/to/lans/files/'
lan_array = ['bg','ca','cs','da','de','el','en','es','fi','fr','hr','hu','it','ja','ko','nl','no','pb','pl','pt','ro','ru','sk','sr','sv','tr','tw','uk','zh']
lan_dict = {}

for lan_code in lan_array:
    line_list = []
    lan_file_name = os.path.join(lans_dir,f'{lan_code}.txt')
    with open(lan_file_name) as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            line_strip = line.strip()
            line_list.append(line_strip)
    lan_dict[lan_code] = line_list

en_lines = lan_dict['en']
for lan_code in lan_array:
    path = os.path.join(f'locale/{lan_code}/LC_MESSAGES/django.po')
    with open(path, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(lan_dict[lan_code]):
            file_out.write(f"#: en.txt:{line_number + 1}\n")
            file_out.write(f"msgid \"{en_line}\"\n")
            file_out.write(f"msgstr \"{line}\"\n\n")
```